BizTalk 2020 SMTP adapter and attached file name
I understand that my problem is very old and looks trivial, but nevertheless...I'm pretty new in creating custom components, I've looked through similar questions here and stuck with one thing.
So, I need to send out email through SMTP adapter with the attached flat file (single, result of previous processing/mapping) with certain name, different from "body". For this I've made a simple component to set this name, it's code as simple as it's possible: it contains only mandatory methods and this:
    public IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pc, IBaseMessage inmsg)
    {

                inmsg.BodyPart.PartProperties.Write(TargetProperty, TargetNamespace, OutgoingAttachedFileName);
                return inmsg;

    }

Where TargetProperty = "FileName", TargetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties" and OutgoingAttachedFileName comes from the component property when setting up the send port (but when testing I tried also to hardcode it as OutgoingAttachedFileName = "somename.ext", it did not help).
I've added this component to the outgoing pipeline (so my pipeline contains FlatFileAssembler and this one) and the result confused me. It impacts only the extension of the attached file. If this component is not present, the attached file has the name "body". But, if it is present, the attached file has the name "body.ext", where .ext is the extension of the filename which I specify in the component property when setting up the send port and which goes to OutgoingAttachedFileName. E.g. if I specify it as "ImportResult.txt", the attached file has the name "body.txt", if I set it to "ParseResult.csv", the attached file is "body.csv", etc.
This completely confused me. Since I'm new to this, I would understand if it would not work at all, but partially working?
Can anyone advise, what am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.
Environment is BT 2020, SMTP adapter settings are pre-defined text and "Attach only body part".
I can't use orchestrations in this solution.
Thanks in advance.

Why oh why do you want to send electronic payloads via email.  See my blog post as to why you should not be doing this.  https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2021/12/10/biztalk-sending-messages-via-email/   It even mentions the exact issue you are having

Does this answer your question? Why is the email atachment i sent by BizTalk "body.csv" in OUTLOOK 2016?

Hi Dijkgraaf,
Thanks for your response.


Well, I've already seen this article in your blog some time ago. You're darn right there, but, you know, our CTO is so old-fashioned person... :)


Yeah, the same issue. It does not give a direct answer for a pipeline (only for orchestration) but now I know that it's related more to
Outlook visualization and will continue from there (on the other hands, now I'm not sure that it's worth wasting time: I tested with Outlook because of the reason above, but it's not critical for the end Customer). So, thank you so much!


